# column "tum_first_name" of relation "tbl_users" does not exist, even when it does

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a `tbl_users`, where there are a few columns like `TUM_First_Name,TUM_Last_Name` and so on. However, when I try an insert query, an error says :-

`column "tum_first_name" of relation "tbl_users" does not exist`

Here is a photo of the schema :-

[image]

Update :-

Surprisingly, after I renamed all the column names to lower cases, and called this same query, it worked.

So, when my table had new column names as `tum_first_name,tum_last_name,` etc., running the query `INSERT INTO tbl_users(TUM_First_Name,TUM_Last_Name,)...` worked fine

What is this ambiguity ?

Comment: Related: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names